# How do I update a single item rather than updating all itmes in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I created a simple todo application using AngularJS.

It displays the `updated date` whenever a single task has been updated, but all my items in my `ng-repeat` list are getting updated with that date.

My `API` will return an array similar to this,

```
[{
    'id' : 1,
    'title' : 'Eat',
    'isCompleted' : false,
    'createdAt' : new Date(),
    'updatedAt' : new Date()
}, {
    'id' : 2,
    'title' : 'Sleep',
    'isCompleted' : false,
    'createdAt' : new Date(),
    'updatedAt' : new Date()
}, {
    'id' : 3,
    'title' : 'Code',
    'isCompleted' : false,
    'createdAt' : new Date(),
    'updatedAt' : new Date()
}]
```

I have this in my `index.html`

```
<ul class="task-list">
    <li ng-repeat="task in tasks | orderBy : 'createdAt' : true">
    <div class="task-container" ng-hide="task.isEditable">
        <div class="checkbox task-detail-container">
            <div class="task-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" value="{{ task.title }}" />
            </div>
            <div class="task-detail" ng-dblclick="isUpdatingTask(task)">
                <div class="task-title">
                    <span>
                        {{ task.title }}
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="task-updated-at">
                    {{ updatedMsg }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="task-option">
            <i class="icon icon-trash-bin trash-bin" ng-click="deleteTask(task)"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So in my `controller.js`, I have

```
$scope.updateTask = function (task) {
    taskFactory.update({
        'id' : task._id
    }, {
        'title' : task.title,
        'isCompleted' : task.isCompleted
    })
};

$scope.$watch('updatedTask', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal !== oldVal) {
        $scope.updatedMsg = 'Modified ' + newVal.updatedAt;
    }
});
```

Comment: Post the full `ng-repeat` html.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a list-item controller. What this will do is create an instance of the controller for the item clicked on in your list. Right now you have one controller for your list and when you update something how is the controller supposed to know which item to update? The controller doesn't and therefore updates everything.

```
app.controller('listItemCtrl',listItemCtrl);

listItemCtrl.$inject =['$scope'];


function listItemCtrl($scope){
  $scope.showMsg = false;
  $scope.updatedMsg ="";

  $scope.updateTask = function (task) {
     task.updatedAt = new Date();
      $scope.showMsg = true;

  var index =  arrayObjectIndexOf($scope.tasks,task.id,'id');
  if(index!==-1){
    $scope.tasks.splice(index,1,task);
     $scope.updatedMsg = 'Modified at: '+task.updatedAt;

  }

  };


/*
$scope.$watch('updatedTask', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal !== oldVal) {
        $scope.updatedMsg = 'Modified';
    }
});*/


}

function arrayObjectIndexOf(myArray, searchTerm, property) {
                for(var i = 0, len = myArray.length; i < len; i++) {
                    if (myArray[i][property] === searchTerm) return i;
                }
                    return -1;
            }
```

Take a look at my plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/jvyyMsSsngeEl74pB5XB?p=preview if you double click it will continue to update the "updatedAt" property.